# Gif doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I find a small script to show a waiting message when my form is submitted. I'm using **jquery-ui** to display this message in the dialog box and it works. After adding some text and **animated gif background** using **CSS**, the image doesn't showing up every time.

Note: Writing the code directly in the developer console works.

```
$("#loading_dialog").loading();
```

The code below makes my dialog box appear without the image.

```
jQuery('form').submit(function(event) {
    $("#loading_dialog").loading();
});
```

**CSS**:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content.ui-dialog-loadingDialog{
    background: url("../img/loader.gif") no-repeat scroll 5px 15px transparent;
    padding: 30px 0 0px 70px;
    border: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
    font-weight: 900;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    color: #737373;
}
```

Edit:

I use a script found there: http://jsfiddle.net/artistan/nx3ce/

My page is very very big, but it's just a

Comment: why not put the gif in an image tag `<img src="../img/loader.gif" />` in the loading_dialog instead of putting it in your css?

Comment: Please post the entire page's HTML. It could be any number of problems.

Comment: you are giving no width and height to that div. that may be it.remove the padding and try with width height values instead

Comment: There are a width and a height.

Comment: The fiddle you have provided shows a working gif image, no errors.

Comment: It work when i call the function manually it work. Problems come in the $().submit(....)

Comment: Perhaps the browser doesn't have enough time to load the file before the page redirects. Perhaps try pre-loading the gif?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to jaypeagi !

I preload image, now i can see my image !

```
        var images = new Array();

        function preload() {
            for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
                images[i] = new Image();
                images[i].src = preload.arguments[i];
            }
        }
        preload("img/loader.gif");
```